# MassTransit (RabbitMq) + Asp.Net Core 2.1: Multiple consumers in the same project

Tags: rabbitmq, producer-consumer, masstransit, asp.net-core-2.1

I've got an Asp.Net 2.1 project that acts as a service host for consuming messages published by other processes/applications. I've setup/configured multiple consumers in the **Startup** class (Startup.cs) as below (only MassTransit portion is given here for brevity):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{   
    services.AddScoped<SendMessageConsumer>();
    services.AddScoped<AnotherMessageConsumer>();
    services.AddMassTransit(c =>
    {
        c.AddConsumer<SendMessageConsumer>();
        c.AddConsumer<AnotherMessageConsumer>();
    });

    services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h => { });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "Queue-1", e =>
        {
            e.PrefetchCount = 16;
            e.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

            e.LoadFrom(provider);
            e.Consumer<SendMessageConsumer>();
            EndpointConvention.Map<Message>(e.InputAddress);                    
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "Queue-2", e =>
        {
            e.PrefetchCount = 16;
            e.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

            e.LoadFrom(provider);
            e.Consumer<AnotherMessageConsumer>();
            EndpointConvention.Map<AnotherMessage>(e.InputAddress);
        });
    }));

    services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();   
}
```

**Messages:**

```
namespace MasstransitDemo.Models
{
    public class Message
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnotherMessage
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Consumers:**

```
public class SendMessageConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Receive message value: {context.Message.Value}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class AnotherMessageConsumer : IConsumer<AnotherMessage>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<AnotherMessage> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Receive another message value: {context.Message.Value}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This causes both messages to come through to each queue. See the resulting RabbitMq exchanges below:

[image]
[image]

How do I set it up to make SendMessageConsumer to receive only "Message" and AnotherMessageConsumer to receive "AnotherMessage"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alexey answered it well below, but the short answer is do NOT use .LoadFrom(), use .Consumer<>(container).

Comment: Thanks Chris - Alexey's suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell MassTransit about your consumer explicitly, but *also* load *all* consumers from the container, for each endpoint.

```
e.LoadFrom(provider);
e.Consumer<AnotherMessageConsumer>();
```

By doing this, you all both consumers to each endpoint with `LoadFrom`, plus one consumer in addition by `Consumer<T>`. So each of your endpoints gets three consumers, and you get both queues bound to both exchanges.

You don't need to use `LoadFromContainer` here. If your consumer has a dependency that needs to be resolved by the container, you can use this:

```
e.Consumer<AnotherMessageConsumer>(container);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. After commenting `e.LoadFrom(provider);` it's working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

It is not working for me. do you commented both `e.loadfrom(provider)`. please share you code snippet to understand

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configurator =>
    {
        IRabbitMqHost rabbitMqHost=configurator.Host(_busConfiguration.RabbitMqUri, _busConfiguration.Port, _busConfiguration.Vhost,hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Username(_busConfiguration.UserName);
            hostConfigurator.Password(_busConfiguration.Password);
        });

        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitMqHost,_busConfiguration.GeneratePayLoadQueue, e =>
        {
            e.PrefetchCount = _busConfiguration.PrefetchCount;
            //e.LoadFrom(provider);
            e.Consumer<StagingConsumerService>(provider);
            EndpointConvention.Map<StagingConsumer>(e.InputAddress);
        });

        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitMqHost, _busConfiguration.CreateJournalQueue , e =>
        {
            e.PrefetchCount = _busConfiguration.PrefetchFinDocCount;
            //e.LoadFrom(provider);
            e.Consumer<FinDocConsumerService>();
            EndpointConvention.Map<FinDocConsumer>(e.InputAddress);
        });
    }));

    services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
```